# access multiple tables in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, relational-database

I have

```
$mySQL = $db -> prepare("SELECT table1.users,table1.name,table2.img,table2.name,table2.users FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.users = table2.users");

$row = $mySQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I can echo out :

```
echo $row['name'];
```

But how does it know to get name from table1 or table2? Can I do something like

```
echo $row['table1.name'];
```

Thanks

Also, is this the best way to get data from multiple tables? Thanks

Comment: u need to put alias and its better to use join to join 2 tables. it will imrove performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add alias to identify your table.

```
SELECT table1.users as tab1user,table1.name,table2.img,table2.name,table2.users as tab2user
 FROM table1 JOIN table2 in table1.users = table2.users
```

Best way to JOIN tables. it'll improve performances.
You have to select suitable join method according to your requirement. follow this link for JOIN

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

**Edit :**
**JOIN 3 Tables**

```
 select ......
 FROM table1 JOIN table2 in table1.users = table2.users
 JOIN Table3 in table2.id=table3.id
```

Comment: can u do join 3 different tables? it seems confusing to me to have three tables use JOIN? would that be possible?

Comment: yah its possible to join 3 tables. but there should be a link between those tables.

Comment: Okay I'll look for examples. Thanks for answer my question

Answer (score 2):

Use [SQL Alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

eg: `SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name`

Answer (score 1):

Try naming the fields:

```
SELECT table1.name AS table1name
```

That will then appear in the result set as `table1name`, so there's no possibility of a conflict.

A join can be a very efficient way of getting data from multiple tables - it very much depends on the structure of your database, the data you want to retrieve, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give different aliass for columns as:

```
SELECT table1.users AS users_1, table2.users AS users_2,
       table1.name AS name_1, table2.name AS name_2, table2.img
FROM table1,table2 
WHERE table1.users = table2.users
```

Answer (score 1):

add alias

```
$mySQL = $db -> prepare("SELECT table1.users AS tbl1users , table1.name AS tbl1name , table2.img AS tbl2img, table2.name as tbl2name, table2.users as tbl2users FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.users = table2.users");
```